# How JPanel Actually Works?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am quite new to Java, I am trying to create a Program where computer draw random circles, rectangles and lines then count their number that are shown right below them.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Shapes extends JPanel{

`   private int noOfCircles;
    private int noOfLines;
    private int noOfRect;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        Random rand = new Random();
        super.paintComponent( g );

        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;

        noOfCircles = 0;
        noOfLines = 0;
        noOfRect = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

            int choice = rand.nextInt(3);

            if(choice == 0){
                noOfLines++;
                g.drawLine(x, y, i*10+50, i+100);
            }
            else if(choice == 1){
                noOfRect++;
                g.drawRect(i*20, y*20, x*10, y *10);
            }
            else{
                noOfCircles++;
                g.drawOval(x*10, i*20, x*10, y*10); 
            }
            x+=5;
            y+=5;

        }

        System.out.println(status());

    }

    public String status(){

        String message = String.format("Circles : %d; Rect : %d; Lines : %d;", noOfCircles, noOfRect, noOfLines);
        return message;
    }

}
```

And

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ShapesTest {

    public static void main( String args[] ){

        Shapes panel     = new Shapes();
        JFrame app       = new JFrame();
        JLabel statusBar = new JLabel();

        String message = panel.status();
        statusBar.setText(message);
        statusBar.setSize(400, 20);

        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.add(panel);
        app.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        app.setSize( 400, 400 );
        app.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Problem is that The Shape Class always returns noOfCircles, noOfLines, noOfRect = 0 no Matter when they are called. I don't get how it actually works

Comment: You've got program logic inside of the paintComponent method, usually a bad idea, and in that logic you re-zero out your int fields at the start of the method. What does your actual assignment state you must do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works and does not update on resize.
Also view and logic are separated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ShapesTest {

    public static void main( String args[] ){

        Shapes panel     = new Shapes();
        JFrame app       = new JFrame();
        JLabel statusBar = new JLabel();

        statusBar.setSize(400, 20);
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.add(panel);
        app.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        app.setSize( 400, 400 );
        app.setVisible(true);

        statusBar.setText(panel.status());

    }

}

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Random;

public class Shapes extends JPanel{
    private static final int TYPE_LINE = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_RECT = 1;
    // private static final int TYPE_OVAL = 2; // not used
    private int[] forms = new int[10];

    private int c = 0, r = 0, l = 0;

    public Shapes() {
        super();

        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
            int choice = rand.nextInt(3);

            if(choice == TYPE_LINE)
                c++;
            else if(choice == TYPE_RECT)
                r++;
            else
                l++;  

            forms[i] = choice;
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;

        for(int i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
            int choice = forms[i];

            if(choice == TYPE_LINE){
                g.drawLine(x, y, i*10+50, i+100);
            }

            else if(choice == TYPE_RECT){
                g.drawRect(i*20, y*20, x*10, y *10);
            }

            else {
                g.drawOval(x*10, i*20, x*10, y*10);    
            }

            x+=5;
            y+=5;
        }
    }

    public String status(){        
        String message = String.format("C:%d;R:%d;L:%d", c, r, l);
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Now its working. Can you please explain what was going wrong with my code. All I can see that increment in objects variables in paintComponent and in any other method works differently.

Comment: I separated the view and the logic, so at the beginning it's calculated how many rectangles, line and circles are painted. so the panel needn't been drawn before `status()` is called. so in your code the status was probably updated before `paintComponent(g)` was executed

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you call

```
String message = panel.status();
statusBar.setText(message);
```

before your JPanel is visible, so it has never been drawn.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ShapesTest {

    public static void main( String args[] ){

        Shapes panel     = new Shapes();
        JFrame app       = new JFrame();
        JLabel statusBar = new JLabel();

        statusBar.setSize(400, 20);

        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.add(panel);
        app.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        app.setSize( 400, 400 );
        app.setVisible(true);

        String message = panel.status();
        statusBar.setText(message);
    }

}
```

With this ShapesTest-class it should work as expected, but as Hovercraft Full Of Eels mentioned you should separate logic (controller) and rendering (view)

Comment: Nice pick up and answer. 1+

Comment: Okay as per Hovercraft Full Of Eels I have seperated the logic from paintComponent, also called setText method after app.setVisible but the problem isn't solved. Still it is showing 0, 0, 0 for circles, rectangles and lines.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/1F3Gpa0W) **Shapes.java**
[link](http://pastebin.com/jM3kgiSR) **ShapesTest.java**
[link](http://pastebin.com/DKGBUrs3) **Counter.java**

Comment: You didn't really separate it, wait a moment, I'll soon post a solution ;)

Comment: I just added a new answer instead of editing my existing one, because it's a totally different solution (this one wasn't really one)